# Use Auth0 passwordless with voice instead of sms

Tags: twilio, auth0

I already have sms working but I need to offer the option to receive the verification code via phone call, is it possible? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here! You can use our Phone Verification API and then pass in the channel ('sms' or 'call') as a parameter like so:

```
// npm install authy
const authy = require("authy")("YOUR_AUTHY_API_KEY");

authy
  .phones()
  .verification_start("5551234567", "1", "sms", function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

    console.log(res.message);
  });
```

Here's the full QuickStart: https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/quickstart/nodejs

Comment: Yes I've used that, but I need to get this working through auth0